# Accepting EBT/Food Stamps via a Payment Gateway

Tags: e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment

A requirement for an online *produce delivery site* states that EBT (food stamps) be accepted as a form of payment.

I was unable to dig up anything on authorize.net or paypal accepting these.

Anyone dealt with this before?

Comment: You may have to look at that requirement again, apparently it's not possible: http://www.fns.usda.gov/snap/faqs.htm#15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EBT foodstamps use their own gateway and require a physical POS terminal that can process the proprietary encryption of the PIN used to validate the card. Additionally, remember that only certain classes of foodstock is eligible for payment by EBT and that the unpublished method for encrypting PIN's for transfer to the EBT authorizing servers is just that, unpublished.  [The long version](http://www.fns.usda.gov/apd/Handbook_901/4.2%20_WIC_EB_final%20amend%20-%206.4.10.pdf)

Comment: Nice thanks, I had a feeling they didn't know what they were talking about :)